# Failed to chmod error while trying to access SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try to use sdb=this.getReadableDatabase() I am getting the following error

```
07-13 07:14:45.990: W/FileUtils(10022): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example.cognizantshopping/databases/ShopDatabase): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

It worked fine in the starting.But after I pushed a file onto the device,my app is not working properly(it's not crashing).I tried to output to the log to see if whether queries are working properly are not.They are working fine but nothing is getting displayed on the emulator while running.
Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the api levels of your different devices?

Comment: I am using emulator with an api level 19

Comment: I have used onCreate() method to initially create database and populate it with some sample data.

Comment: everytime i start my app on the emulator,it is getting initiated with the data that I used as sample data for initiating the database through onCreate().So is there a way around to maintain a persistent database?